# Protractor check if modal closed. browser.waitForAngular

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to click the cancel button on an angular bootstrap modal. This should close the modal, which it does. I want to test that the modal is no longer visible and I am using the WebElement.isDisplayed() promise. I notice if I do **NOT** use browser.waitForAngular my test will NOT pass. The following code **DOES** work (I have defined my own page objects)

```
variableExpenseModal.cancel();
browser.waitForAngular();
expect(variableExpenseModal.modalIsDisplayed()).toEqual(false);
```

Is this the proper way to test this? Should I use browser.waitForAngular? Or am I missing some way to use promises to do this? Please advise.

Comment: as I read more perhaps the transitions are causing some of the issue.

Comment: I found it is best to use isPresent for the modal because it removed from the DOM when you dismiss/close it. Also I found it was useful to turn off all animations in my protractor config in the onprepare. I still had to use the browser.waitForAngular() but I now do not get the intermittent failures due to the transitions and animation.

Answer (score 2):

The fix for my problem was to remove the animation in my conf.js (config) file.

```
onPrepare: function () {        

    // Disable animations so e2e tests run more quickly
    //this will also prevent failure that are intermittent due to transitions
    var disableNgAnimate = function () {
        angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function ($animate) {
            $animate.enabled(false);
        }]);
    };

    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
}
```

It was the transition/animation on the Modal that was causing my problem. also it was better for me to use isPresent() instead of isDisplayed(). When I did that I was able to remove the browser.waitForAngular()

```
it('click the save button and the modal should not be displayed', () => {
    variableExpenseModal.save();
    expect(variableExpenseModal.isPresent()).toEqual(false);
});
```

Note: My code is using a page object.